# SSIS transfer files by ftp with limited transfer speed

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, ftp

I need to transfer via ftp sql server backup with ssis to a limited speed, is this possible with ssis ?
I can´t find anything with google search.

I have a remote WAN location with limited network bandwidth and would transfer without affecting too much the bandwidth.

I need it without Third party applications.

I have been able to see that with the component script in c# you can enlarge the functionality I think that over there the thing walks.

It would appreciate the help of the community

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the simplicity of many SSIS controls, I doubt there's a way to throttle it built-in.

An alternative may be to throttle the network on the SSIS process, however [judging by this question](https://superuser.com/questions/135719/how-can-i-limit-bandwidth-of-other-programs), there may not be a way built-in to Windows to achieve this.

[Others have asked this question as well](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9864fc59-d278-484d-b146-645fe3375e9a/ftp-task-but-with-limited-transfer-speed-is-this-possible-?forum=sqlintegrationservices), but as you may have found, it required third party applications too.